# Python calculator with the math.sqrt function

Tags: python, calculator, math.sqrt

I am very new to Python but I wanted to code an calculator. It works fine exept for the sqrt function. Everytime I try to calculate the square root of a number I get the error message. 
I know that there are probably thousand ways to code a better calculator but I would really like to know what I did wrong and how I can fix this. 
This is my code:

```
import math

no1 = float(input('Insert a number: '))
operator = input("Operator: ").upper()
result = no1

while operator != "=":
    if (operator) == "-":
        no2 = float(input('Insert next number: '))
        result = result - no2
        operator = input("Operator: ").upper()
    elif (operator) == "/":
        no2 = float(input('Insert next number: '))
        result = result / no2
        operator = input("Operator: ").upper()
    elif (operator) == "+":
        no2 = float(input('Insert next number: '))
        result = result + no2
        operator = input("Operator: ").upper()
    elif (operator) == "*":
        no2 = float(input('Insert next number: '))
        result = result * no2
        operator = input("Operator: ").upper()
    elif (operator) == "^":
        no2 = float(input('Insert next number: '))
        result = math.pow(result,no2)
        operator = input("Operator: ").upper()
    elif (operator) == "sqrt":
        result = math.sqrt(no1)
    else:
        print('Error!')
        operator = "="

print(result)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: "I get the error message" — What error message?

Comment: Your `elif (operator) == "sqrt"` block doesn't reassign `operator`. So if this case _did_ match, your `while operator != "="` would go into an infinite loop.

Comment: The one from    else: print('Error!')

Comment: You make the operator uppercase, but then check against lowercase sqrt. That will always fail.

Comment: @khelwood. It doesn't get triggered

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You convert the operator to upper case but the elif has lower case 'sqrt'.

Change it to

```
elif (operator) == "SQRT":
    result = math.sqrt(no1)
```

Comment: Yes I will. But according to stackoverflow I need to wait a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the input to a uppercase, but then testing for `'sqrt'`. Test for `'SQRT'` instead. You will also want to remove the `while` loop otherwise it will never exit.